# Check if a class extends a different class in PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, class-hierarchy

I have approximately this PHP code:

```
class DatabaseItem
{
  private const CLASS_NAMES = null;
  public function doStuff()
  {
    if ($this::CLASS_NAMES['property'] instanceof self)
    {
      //Construct the Profile Picture object and save it into the property of the $user instance
    }
  }
}

class ProfilePicture extends DatabaseItem { /* Unimportant stuff */ }

class User extends DatabaseItem
{
  protected const CLASS_NAMES = array('property' => ProfilePicture);

  protected $profilePic;
}

$user = new User();
$user->doStuff();
```

I know that this code looks pretty unlogical, but I had to simplify it a lot. Anyway, the problem is, that the condition `($this::CLASS_NAMES['property'] instanceof self)` always evaluates to false. Is there a way to check if a class (not its instance) extends or implements a different class/interface?

Comment: The second operand of `instanceof` should be a class, not a class instance.

Comment: I think you just have it backwards: `$this instanceof $this::CLASS_NAMES['property']`

Comment: `doStuff()` requires a `$user` argument, but you're calling it with an empty argument list.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but the problem is, that I don't have an instance of any of the classes. I just know their names. As a result, I can't use $this. In the example, I am trying to find out, if the class `ProfilePicture` extends the `DatabaseItem` class, which it does.

About that missing `$user` argument, that was just a typo, already fixed it.

Comment: `array('property' => ProfilePicture)` <- this is invalid, this will look for a constant called `ProfilePicture`. Did you mean `ProfilePicture::class`?

Comment: Maybe `$this::CLASS_NAMES['property'] instanceof self::class`?

Comment: No, that's not right. You need a `subclassof` operator, not `intanceof`.

Comment: Thanks guys, looks like one or both of your ideas will work. I already closed my IDE, but I will try it tomorrow and let you know if it solved my problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're attempting to achieve and what that condition within `doStuff` is supposed to check? Thanks.

Comment: Basically, I have an abstract class DatabaseItem from which all models representing records in various database tables inherit. There is a load() method implemented in the DatabaseItem class, which loads the record from the database table and saves the data into the object's properties. However, some properties store references to other objects (such as Post class has a property $user, which stores a reference to its author). In the database, there is just an ID of the user saved, so when I load it, I need to know what class I need to instantiate.

Comment: And the constant CLASS_NAMES links properties to the classes whose instances must be stored in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `is_subclass_of()` function.

```
if (is_subclass_of(self::CLASS_NAMES['property'], get_class($this)))
```

Comment: [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php#115849) says it's in version >= 5.5.

Comment: Ah, that only works for literal class names, not variables.

Comment: Oh, cool! It looks like what I need. Just a little question: could I user `self` instead of `$this::class`? It looks more smooth to me, but I am not sure if I can do that.

Comment: Of course, I was just confusing different languages.

Comment: `$self` is a variable like any other though. `if (is_subclass_of(self::CLASS_NAMES['property'], __CLASS__))` is probably what you meant, Barmar. But in that case it wouldn't work because `CLASS_NAMES` is null in `DatabaseItem`, so I think your previous answer was correct.

Comment: But anyway, this question is pretty confusing and it's late, so I'll stop commenting.

Comment: I think I got it right now. `$this` is the variable, `self` is a keyword that can be used to refer to static/const properties.

Comment: Seems syntaxically correct to me, but `self::CLASS_NAMES` will always be null because it's defined as such in `DatabaseItem`. And `get_class($this)` will be `User`. The only way to make OP's condition work is to do this: `if (is_subclass_of(static::CLASS_NAMES['property'], __CLASS__))`. I'm gonna ask to clarify what his goal is.

Comment: If I've gotten details wrong, feel free to post a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your suggestions and what worked for me was changing

`protected const CLASS_NAMES = array('property' => ProfilePicture);`
to
`protected const CLASS_NAMES = array('property' => ProfilePicture::class);`

and then changing

`if ($this::CLASS_NAMES['property'] instanceof self)`
to
`if (is_subclass_of($this::CLASS_NAMES['property'], __CLASS__))`

So I used all of your answers at once. Thanks a lot for your help.

P.S. I am not sure if I shouldn't post this in comments, but I thought that a conclusion should be clearly visible.